# I want to create a horizontal cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I'm looking to create a horizontal cursor for my website, similar in style to the Git Bash terminal cursor. And I have no idea how to do it. This does not exist in CSS properties... Do you have any ideas ?   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkLDy.png)

I searched on the internet and tried to create a horizontal bar acting as a cursor in css.

I use html, css and js in my code.

Comment: In CSS there is a property called **cursor**: `cursor: url(‘path-to-image.png’), auto;`
In this case it will default to auto if it fails to use the image. Altough `png` is good, I would suggest that you use an `svg`.